# Does prophet Musa has been given the ability to talk directly with Allah A.Z.W ? And does Prophet Muhammad S.A.W was also given that ability?

Tags: hadith, prophets

According the hadith below prophet Musa A.S is given the ability to talk directly with Allah A.Z.W.

حَدَّثَنَا عَلِيُّ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، قَالَ حَفِظْنَاهُ مِنْ عَمْرٍو عَنْ طَاوُسٍ، سَمِعْتُ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ احْتَجَّ آدَمُ وَمُوسَى، فَقَالَ لَهُ مُوسَى يَا آدَمُ أَنْتَ أَبُونَا خَيَّبْتَنَا وَأَخْرَجْتَنَا مِنَ الْجَنَّةِ‏.‏ قَالَ لَهُ آدَمُ يَا مُوسَى اصْطَفَاكَ اللَّهُ بِكَلاَمِهِ، وَخَطَّ لَكَ بِيَدِهِ، أَتَلُومُنِي عَلَى أَمْرٍ قَدَّرَ اللَّهُ عَلَىَّ قَبْلَ أَنْ يَخْلُقَنِي بِأَرْبَعِينَ سَنَةً‏.‏ فَحَجَّ آدَمُ مُوسَى، فَحَجَّ آدَمُ مُوسَى ‏"‏ ثَلاَثًا‏.‏ قَالَ سُفْيَانُ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو الزِّنَادِ، عَنِ الأَعْرَجِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم مِثْلَهُ‏.‏

Narrated Abu Huraira: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Adam and Moses argued with each other. Moses said to Adam. 'O Adam! You are our father who disappointed us and turned us out of Paradise.' Then Adam said to him, 'O Moses! Allah favored you with His talk (talked to you directly) and He wrote (the Torah) for you with His Own Hand. Do you blame me for action which Allah had written in my fate forty years before my creation?' So Adam confuted Moses, Adam confuted Moses," the Prophet (ﷺ) added, repeating the Statement three times.

Sahih al-Bukhari 6614
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6614

Did the Prophet Musa A.S talk with Allah A.Z.W while on earth or by mean of angel-messengers.
Also in the story of Mi‘raaj night journey Allah A.Z.W talk directly with Prophet S.A.W .
While on earth , does Prophet S.A.W talk with Allah A.Z.W directly or by mean of angel-messengers.